# Changes not detected in pull requests on Jenkins pipeline plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins configured to build on pull requests (PR). Our repository is a multi project repository and I have created a script to detect the changes that were made to source code and only run tests that are relevant to the projects that had changes in them (according to the changed file's path):

```
def getChangedProjects() {
  Set projects = []
  def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
  for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
      def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
      for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
          def entry = entries[j]
          def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
          for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
            def file = files[k]
            // get the project folder name and
            // add it to changed projects set
            projects.add(file.path.tokenize('/')[1])
          }
      }
  }
  return projects.findAll {it != null}
}
```

The Groovy function works as expected and detects the folder that has changed.

Problem is that most of the times Jenkins will not show any changes in Jenkins:

[image: Changes are not shown]

But the PR did contain changes to files and I can see these changes in Github of course.

Anyone know why Jenkins is not showing the changes ?

Comment: So just to be clear... the build happens, but the Changes/commits aren't getting reflected in the Change Tab ?

Comment: You have shown that it does not reflect in BlueOcen UI.... can you confirm if the changes(log) get reflected on Jenkins normal UI ??

Comment: @rohitthomas they are not reflected there either. and yes, build triggers, but no changes

Comment: does this happen on other jobs also or only on this one ?? Also is upgrading an option ?

Answer (score 1):

You may create a change log by including a [Git Changelog](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git-changelog/) step in the Jenkins pipeline script.

This [plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-changelog) provides a [context object](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-lib#context) that contains all the information needed to create a changelog. It can also provide a [string](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-lib#usage) that is a rendered changelog, ready to be published.

[Here](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-lib/blob/screenshots/sandbox/example_github.png) is a screenshot of a sample Git changelog produced by this plugin:

[image: Git Changelog]

More information about this plugin may be found in its [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Changelog+Plugin). 
Hope, it helps.